# I am using MS Access as an API for Twilio SMS, I need to know why sending SMS in spanish with spanish characters use 3 times the amount of segments

Tags: twilio, ms-access-2010

I need to know how to prevent spanish characters from trippling the size of my segments used.

I have just done research on fixing this issue but I cant find a good solution.
It sounds like a twilio glitch but I am not sure

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Twilio uses GSM-7 encoding, however when there are characters in the message not covered by GSM-7, they switch to UCS-2 encoding, using more segments.

You can use the [Messaging Segment Calculator](https://twiliodeved.github.io/message-segment-calculator/) tool to figure which characters are responsible for switching the message to UCS-2.